# Ionic - Opening a modal from within a popover causes DOM to not function in iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I noticed a small issue with trying to open a modal from within a popover. in iOS on both my iPhone 6S Plus as well as the emulators, when I open these modals, the DOM becomes non-responsive. Text areas refuse to be clicked into, buttons won’t run functions when tapped. Buttons in the `<ion-navbar>` will work. Text inputs or textareas in the `<ion-navbar>` WON’T work.

Then, of course, in my `<ion-content>`, nothing will work, buttons, text areas, anything with a `(tap)` or `(click)`. Has anyone else had this issue?

I should note that when I’m trying to open the modal from a page or other component, it doesn’t have this issue, ONLY when opened from a popover. Is this a bug within Ionic or could I be doing something wrong? No error shows up in my console for any of this. I could post some of my code, but the code is pretty much identical between opening the modal from the popover vs opening the modal from a regular page or component.

Thanks in advance, this is really weird :D

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to `app.scss` solved the problem in iOS. I haven't seen any issues arise from doing this:

```
.disable-scroll .ion-page {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Your answer does not seem to fix my problem when the app gets opened through a browser in an iOS device. I have the same issue but it only happens with a specific modal which is being opened from an actionsheet. I have the exact same logic in a different page and for some reason it seems to be working fine even before your answer...

Answer (score 0):

My quick fix for this issue is similar to @StevieStar solution, but I applied it to the opener classes for both Popovers and modals as it can happen with either kind of window because they are all kept in the same `modalStack`

In your custom css file

```
.modal-open{ pointer-events: all ; }
.popover-open { pointer-events: all ; }
```

This fix does not override a modal's or popover's behavior when `backdropClickToClose:false` is set either.  The surroundiung area is still not clickable.